# how to detect scroll to bottom when page is scaled (resized)?

Tags: javascript, scroll, scale, detect

I detect scroll to bottom to load a new page (here a message):

```
window.onscroll = function(ev) {
    if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.height) { 
        alert("scrolled to bottom");
    }
};
```

If I now scale (resize) the content of the page, for example an image, (on my android 2.2) the function is triggered without that the bottom of the page has actually be seen.

I tried to use other properties than document.height, in the hope they would change when scaled, but they don't:

```
alert("1="+document.documentElement.clientHeight+
      " 2="+window.innerHeight+
      " 3="+window.outerHeight+
      " 4="+document.body.clientHeight+
      " 5="+document.body.offsetHeight+
      " 6="+document.body.scrollHeight+
      " 7="+document.documentElement.clientHeight+
      " 8="+document.documentElement.offsetHeight+
      " 9="+document.documentElement.scrollHeight);
```

shows the same numbers no matter of how much the page is scaled on the mobile phone.

I thought, I'd place a div that has to be passed, but the position of the div stays the same, independent of scaling...:

```
var div = document.getElementById ("mydiv");
var rect = div.getBoundingClientRect ();
x = rect.left;
y = rect.top;
w = rect.right - rect.left;
h = rect.bottom - rect.top;
alert ("left: " + x + " top: " + y + " width: " + w + " height: " + h);
```

How can I detect, when a user REALLY has scrolled to the bottom, e.g. has seen the complete image and scrolled further...?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when I wanted to load some more content  when the page scrolled to the bottom.

I resolved it by adding an empty element at the bottom of the page (after the last loaded content) and checked if it is visible or by this command:

```
if($("#LoadIndicator")[0].getBoundingClientRect().bottom < window.innerHeight + 50)
{
    //Processing...
}
```

LoadIndicator is the ID of the element, and I considered 50 pixels as the distance to the bottom of the page to load next content.

Hope it help